# HTML - Two divs side by side

Tags: html, css

I need to get two divs side by side while one is centered and the other fixed. I already make them side by side.

The problem is that while the float of the green div is right I can't make the position of it fixed. So when I scroll, it does not stay on the screen.

[image: Problem]

Sorry for the colors :) Just for test.

```
#Body {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 800px;
    background: #000;
}

#pinkdiv{
    position: relative;
    background: #F09;
}

#greediv{
    position: fixed;
    float:right;
    width:250px;
    background: #0F0;
}
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Floating the element takes it out of the document flow, if you want to use fixed positioning you're going to have to position the div to the right by using `right:0;`

Answer (score 2):

You can't use float on a fixed element. Instead you need to use `right: 0` as others have suggested. You will also need to add `top: 0` if you want your green element all the way in the top, right corner.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PPfZX/)

```
#greediv{
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width:250px;
    background: #0F0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `float:right`, which won't work with a fixed position as you discovered, set `right:0`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by javascript:

```
if(window.scrollTop() > 0){
  document.getElementById('elementId').style.position="fixed";
}
```

This will fix the div position when you are scrolling.